# MS Access Textbox.OldValue equivalent for DateTime Format

Tags: ms-access

When we update a bound textbox on a form, we can use the `_BeforeUpdate` event to perform logical checks and controls before the update, and reset the textbox to it's previous value using the `txtboxfield.OldValue` property if so desired.

This does not work if the underlying bound is a DateTime field.

Is there an equivalent for the DateTime field? If not, is there a workaround that I could use in the following piece of code?

```
Private Sub txtDueDate1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
'Alert if inital due date is modfied

If Not (Me.txtDueDate1 = vbNullString) Then

    Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to modify the original due date?", _
                vbOKCancel Or vbInformation, "Original Due Date")
        Case vbOK
            Exit Sub
        Case vbCancel 'reset the previous value
            Me.txtDueDate2.SetFocus
            Cancel = True
            Me.txtDueDate1.OldValue
            'Me!txtDueDate1.Undo
    End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Using the `.Undo` option doesn't work for me, as I with to use `.SetFocus` which gets blocked by...

> run time error 2108: You must save the field before you can execute...

I have experimented with moving the `.SetFocus` command arround, but it does not matter where it is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_BeforeUpdate` will not allow you to perform another `save` while `current BeforeUpdate` is being executed. It's like the transaction is locked until this event is completed.

You can undo the current field and cancel the event by:

```
Me!txtDueDate1.Undo
Cancel = True
```

If you require editing/modifying other fields, you can either move this code to `OnAfterUpdate` or move all validations to your Form's`OnBeforeUpdate` on which you can then `halt` the entire update process

Comment: But if I use that and want to set the Focus on a different field, I get the error message

Comment: Works for me in Access 2010. Are there any other event procedures involved? @rohrl77

Comment: Having just typed out an answer, I realize that my problem has shifted from simply undoing the user change (to which your answer is correct - i'll mark it as such) to undoing the user change and setting the focus to a different control on the form. I'll set it up as a new question. Thank you!